# How do I import Python libraries that were installed into another directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, anaconda

I used conda to install some packages into a directory on my c: drive that is not in the default path.  How can I import these libraries?  Can this be done within a Jupyter notebook?  Eg, "import numpy from c:\mydirectory"

Comment: you could always ```import sys; sys.path.insert(0, <path>)```  where ```path``` is the root directory.  though the side effect is that you could be accessing stuff that you shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

You can add that directory to sys path before importing the package.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/directory/')
```

If the package is in many directories, you can add your directory to the beginning of the sys path list. Use

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/')
```